# What does samAccountType in groups of Active Directory mean?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I'm using this query by C# in Active Directory:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + this.rootLDAP);
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(&(objectcategory=Group))");
```

It works just fine.

But one of the properties which it returns is called "samAccountType" and it has the below values :

```
268435456
268435457
536870912
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SAM-Account-Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679635.aspx) (mentioned in your question's title) is the short name of the group.

It's there to provide compatibility with Windows NT 4 / Windows 98 systems, where account names (including group names) were limited to 19 characters.

[SAM-Account-Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220839.aspx) (mentioned in your question's body) is the account type. It can take the following values:

```
SAM_DOMAIN_OBJECT              0x0
SAM_GROUP_OBJECT               0x10000000
SAM_NON_SECURITY_GROUP_OBJECT  0x10000001
SAM_ALIAS_OBJECT               0x20000000
SAM_NON_SECURITY_ALIAS_OBJECT  0x20000001
SAM_USER_OBJECT                0x30000000
SAM_MACHINE_ACCOUNT            0x30000001
SAM_TRUST_ACCOUNT              0x30000002
SAM_APP_BASIC_GROUP            0x40000000
SAM_APP_QUERY_GROUP            0x40000001
```

Not surprisingly (since you're working with groups), the numbers in your question map to `SAM_GROUP_OBJECT`, `SAM_NON_SECURITY_GROUP_OBJECT` and `SAM_ALIAS_OBJECT`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It's an identifier for the object type, See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I have more than 700 groups and each group has one of that three numbers as value.   do you know what is the meaning of each of them ?